# How do I update the PrimaryEntity of a CRM 2011 Workflow plugin from C#?

Tags: c#, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

So, ordinarily in a CRM Plugin, I would access the primary entity by using the following code:

```
(Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]
```

I've noticed this still works from the Create context of a Workflow; however, from the ad-hoc usage, I must use the following:

```
context.PreEntityImages.FirstOrDefault().Value
```

At any rate, once I have the Primary Entity, I run into the nasty problem where the Context does not recognize this value as being the value already in context.  I have tried using an explicit Attach and UpdateObject prior to using Update, however, I receive an exception telling me this entity is already in context under a different object.

I'm sure it'll be obvious in hindsight.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by ad-hoc usage? Are you saying that the syntax in the first example isn't working?

Comment: I probably should just go ahead and delete this question.  My real issue was that even after getting to the entity, I received an exception telling that primary entity was already part of the context through a different object.  I got around the issue by setting each modified entity to context.UpdateObject and then saving through context.SaveChanges (this is the context from crmsvcutil).  
By ad-hoc, I mean, if I go to a grid with the entity and select it and then hit run workflow.

Comment: I'd leave the question be. It might be useful to somebody someday. :)

Comment: @Mike_Matthews_II it is perfectly fine to answer your own question. This would also remove the question from the unanswered list ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the issue by setting each modified entity to context.UpdateObject and then saving through context.SaveChanges (this is the context from crmsvcutil)